# Badge disappears for an app after an hour of no usage?

Tags: ios

I have a todo app that shows a badge indicating how many tasks are due today. For some reason, recently the badge will disappear one hour after I last opened the app. The app has not been updated in months, and I talked with the developers and they can't figure out what the problem might be.

Could this be somehow a problem with iOS, perhaps? And if so, is there a fix I can perform for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding of iOS is that apps in the background will be “killed” if the OS runs into memory pressure.  Could it be that after that hour (is it exactly an hour or is the time random), the app gets killed, and the badge goes away?

You can test this by ending the app yourself.  With your phone unlocked, double click the home button.  You’ll see the last used apps at the very bottom of your phone.  Hold it for a minute and it’ll start wiggling.  Press the (-) sign and if your badge goes away, you may have found your problem.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Removing the app from memory didn't remove the badge, so it doesn't look like the app being removed from memory is the cause for this. And no, it doesn't always happen at exactly one hour; it can be 15 minutes and up.